# I can't load external image to the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have JavaScript code.

```
 <canvas id="view" width="120" height="120">
  błąd
 </canvas>
 <script>
 var _view = document.getElementById("view");
 if(_view.getContext) {
  var canvas = _view.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "fajnetlo.png";
  canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50);
 }
 </script>
```

In the canvas image isn't displayable. Image and file is in one directory. Web browser rectangle etc. drawing, or image not. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Do the drawImage in the onLoad callback of the image. MDN quote:

> When this script gets executed, the
>   image starts loading. Trying to call
>   drawImage before the image has
>   finished loading will throw in gecko
>   1.9.2 and earlier, and silently do nothing in Gecko 2.0 and later.  So
>   you must use an onload event handler:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.onload = function(){
    // execute drawImage statements here
}; 
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="view" width="120" height="120">
błąd
</canvas>
<script>
var view = document.getElementById("view");

var ctx= view.getContext("2d");


img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50);
}
img.src = 'fajnetlo.png';

</script>
```